# TextView in RecyclerView is not showed up

Tags: android, websocket, android-recyclerview, java-websocket

I've been trying to fix my code for a long time. I looked so so many places to find a solution but no avail. If you look at my code and show me why my TextViews in RecylerView is not showed, that'd be great.

I am trying to use WebSocket-ing and fetch data from internet. That should be displayed in the RecyclerView in a constantly updated way. Data ledgers from ripple servers are coming with a natural delay. I want to show their some aspects in RecyclerView. All TextViews can change in content, they are just to try it out.

Here is my WebSocketActivity code:

```
package com.example.menes.searchcode.Websocketing;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.menes.searchcode.R;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.drafts.Draft;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class WebSocketActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyWebSocketAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    private RecyclerView webSocketRecyclerView;// = findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
    private MyWebSocketAdapter myWebSocketAdapter;
    List<LedgerResult> adapterLedgerResultList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.websocket_and_button_thing);

        Button startWebsocketButton = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        final Button stopWebSocketButton = findViewById(R.id.stopButton);

        startWebsocketButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                  if(adapterLedgerResultList.size() == 0)
                        Toast.makeText(WebSocketActivity.this,"Yes it is empty!, nice.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    myWebSocketAdapter = new MyWebSocketAdapter(WebSocketActivity.this, adapterLedgerResultList);
                    webSocketRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
                    webSocketRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                    webSocketRecyclerView.setAdapter(myWebSocketAdapter);

                    final MySimpleClient c = new MySimpleClient( new URI( "wss://s2.ripple.com:443" ));
                    c.connect();

                    stopWebSocketButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                         c.close();
                        }
                    });

                } catch (URISyntaxException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(WebSocketActivity.this,"URISyntaxException occurred. Try again!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void bindIt () {

       //webSocketRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

       myWebSocketAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

       webSocketRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //webSocketRecyclerView.setAdapter(myWebSocketAdapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LedgerDisplayActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", adapterLedgerResultList.get(position).getLedger_hash());
        startActivity(intent);

       //Toast.makeText(this,"Hey there, you onClicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public List<LedgerResult> addToadapterLedgerResultList (LedgerResult ledgerResult1){

        if(adapterLedgerResultList.size() != 0) {
            adapterLedgerResultList.add(ledgerResult1);

           /* myWebSocketAdapter.notifyItemInserted(adapterLedgerResultList.indexOf(ledgerResult1));
            webSocketRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapterLedgerResultList.indexOf(ledgerResult1));*/

            myWebSocketAdapter.notifyItemInserted(adapterLedgerResultList.size() - 1);
            //myWebSocketAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            webSocketRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(adapterLedgerResultList.size() - 1);

            return adapterLedgerResultList;
        }
        else {
            adapterLedgerResultList.add(ledgerResult1);
            myWebSocketAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
           //myWebSocketAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return adapterLedgerResultList;
        }
    }


    public class MySimpleClient extends WebSocketClient {

        public MySimpleClient( URI serverUri , Draft draft ) {
            super( serverUri, draft );
        }

        public MySimpleClient( URI serverURI ) {
            super( serverURI );
        }

        public MySimpleClient( URI serverUri, Map<String, String> httpHeaders ) {
            super(serverUri, httpHeaders);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOpen( ServerHandshake handshakedata ) {
            send("{\n" +
                    "  \"id\": 1,\n" +
                    "  \"command\": \"subscribe\",\n" +
                    "  \"accounts\": [],\n" +
                    "  \"streams\": [\n" +
                    "    \"server\",\n" +
                    "    \"ledger\"\n" +
                    "  ]\n" +
                    "}");
            Log.d("SearchCode", "Connection opened!");
            // if you plan to refuse connection based on ip or httpfields overload: onWebsocketHandshakeReceivedAsClient
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String message) {

            try {

                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(message);

                Gson gson = new Gson();

                LedgerResult ledgerResult =  gson.fromJson(obj.toString(),LedgerResult.class);
                StreamExceptionHandler lilHandler = gson.fromJson(obj.toString(),StreamExceptionHandler.class);

                if(lilHandler.getBase_fee() != null){
                    //do nothing.
                }else {

                    adapterLedgerResultList = addToadapterLedgerResultList(ledgerResult);

                    if(adapterLedgerResultList.get(0).getLedger_index() == null){
                        LedgerResult tmp = adapterLedgerResultList.get(0);
                        adapterLedgerResultList.remove(tmp);
                        myWebSocketAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(0);
                       // myWebSocketAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else {

                        bindIt();

                        Log.d("This is obj", obj.toString());
                        Log.d("LedgerResult", ledgerResult.toString());
                    }
                }

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("SeachCode", "Could not parse malformed JSON: \"" + message + "\"");
            }

        }


        @Override
        public void onClose( int code, String reason, boolean remote ) {
            Log.e("SearchCode: ","Connection closed by " + ( remote ? "remote peer" : "us" ) + " Code: " + code + " Reason: " + reason);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError( Exception ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And my adapter code MyWebSocketAdapter is here:

```
package com.example.menes.searchcode.Websocketing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.menes.searchcode.R;

import java.util.List;

public class MyWebSocketAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyWebSocketAdapter.WebSocketView> {

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick (int position);
    }

    private MyWebSocketAdapter.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
    private Context context;
    private List<LedgerResult> adapterLedgerResultList;

    public MyWebSocketAdapter(Context context, List<LedgerResult> adapterLedgerResultList){
        this.context = context;
        this.adapterLedgerResultList = adapterLedgerResultList;
    }

    /*public MyWebSocketAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }*/

    /*public List<LedgerResult> addToadapterLedgerResultList (LedgerResult ledgerResult1){

        adapterLedgerResultList.add(ledgerResult1);

       if(adapterLedgerResultList.size() != 0) {
            notifyItemInserted(adapterLedgerResultList.indexOf(ledgerResult1));
            return adapterLedgerResultList;
        }
        else {
            notifyItemInserted(0);
            return adapterLedgerResultList;
        }
    }*/

    public void setOnItemClickListener(MyWebSocketAdapter.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        this.onItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }

    class WebSocketView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView otherThing;
        TextView hashCode, textView;

        public WebSocketView(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            hashCode =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.hashCode);
            otherThing = itemView.findViewById(R.id.otherThing);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public WebSocketView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.in_recycler, parent, false);
        return new WebSocketView(layoutView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(WebSocketView holder, final int position) {

        final WebSocketView hldr = holder;

        LedgerResult row = adapterLedgerResultList.get(hldr.getAdapterPosition());

        if(row.getLedger_hash() == null) {
            holder.hashCode.setText("IT IS NULL");
        }
        else {
            holder.hashCode.setText(row.getLedger_hash());
            holder.hashCode.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#239DEA"));
        }

        if(row.getLedger_index() == null) {
            holder.otherThing.setText("IT IS NULL");
        }
        else {
            holder.otherThing.setText(row.getLedger_index().toString());
        }


        if(row.getLedger_index() != null) {
            String s = row.getValidated_ledgers().toString();
            holder.textView.setText(s);
            //holder.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }




       holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(onItemClickListener != null) {
                    onItemClickListener.onItemClick(hldr.getAdapterPosition());
                }
            }
        });
    }

   /* @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }*/

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return adapterLedgerResultList.size();
    }
}
```

My XML files which I have also checked millions of times and even re-created.

websocket_and_button_thing.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Start"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/stopButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="Stop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="363dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And finally the inside-of-recyclerView code is called in-recycler.xml and it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="94dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hashCode" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hashCode"
        android:layout_width="261dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/otherThing"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/otherThing"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Anyone is able to come up with a solution why TextViews are not showed up?

From the LOG records I can get **all the data** From debugging, my lists are working correct as well.

Note: I used the StreamExceptionHandler class to differentiate between two stream outcomes. One is useful to me, other is not and that's why I do not do anything if I catch anything.

Plus, my custom classes are working correctly since my lists seems to be well working.

**AFTER EDIT:**

I changed the WebSocketActivity and adapter as such. No so much changed. But now, again strangely, I am gettin all the data. It is added to RecyclerView too, but it does not show itself until I try to scroll manually. Plus, whenever a new data is arrived, RecyclerView completely disappears, then if I scroll again, it gets back with the updated data. **ANY SOLUTION after update?**

Comment: have you checked that in your adapter's onBindViewHolder() method the data is also being assigned to textviews ?

Comment: So your `RecyclerView` items are displaying but they are blank because the `TextView` don't show. Are you sure that `row.getLedger_hash()` and `row.getLedger_hash()` return non-zero length strings? Simple, but it happens: I would also make sure that the background and the text color are not the same.

Comment: Strange thing is when I put breakpoints to those textview assignments, it sometimes come to there and sometimes they don't. No idea why. When it does though, I saw the assignments to TextView works correctly. Still, it does not show up.

Comment: For the non-zero length strings, I can say yes they are because I checked how the lists are formed and their components are taken right. getAdapterPosition method takes them correctly too. Any comment on general structure ? I was more worried about where I initialize the adapter and where I set it. I also tried different layoutManager initialization and assignment types but result is same.

Comment: Can you guys come up with something after I edited? @Umair

Comment: @bengongon97 it's wired that means data is assigned to recyclerview but it's not shown. Have you tried giving background to your recyclerView maybe you can find out something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, I found it. Since I changed the systematic and the code itself I cannot post the exact code to solve it but the key is overriding the `runOnUiThread` function within the button click. And you should change the `RecyclerView` binding and manager sets as well. Do it in a different place.

To override the `runOnUiThread` in an anonymous (inner) class, use this:

```
 MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                });
```

Hope this helps the future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see this line in MyWebSocketAdapter:

```
holder.textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: I actually put it to make sure that TextView is visible. But it didn't change the result.

Comment: You mean invisible

Comment: Ah, no. I mean visible. What I mean is, I normally did not see the line before I put that setVisibility line. I just wanted to make sure that I explicitly set the visibility. Nothing happened, still, I do not see it.

Comment: *I just wanted to make sure that I explicitly set the visibility* to **INVISIBLE**?

Comment: Ah, I am so sorry. I am so concerned with the code so I cannot read what I wrote. I was thinking I had written VISIBLE there. Yes, now, changed it to VISIBLE and nothing changed. I changed the initialization of adapter and some little stuff, but still nothing changed. I'll check whether the notifyItemInserted() works.

Comment: Have you checked the textcolor? Is there any chance that it is the same as the background color?

Comment: I explicitly changed the color of the text to something would be clearly visible. (I did not  already touch the default colors but anyways) I see that nothing changed but another strange thing is now I am debugging and I put breakpoints to onBindViewHolder. It does not come there! I mean not at all! I do not know why. Although I see sometimes it went there, my last debug trials ended since it did not enter the onBind function. How come it is even possible?